# Table overflowing containing div in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a table which overflows its containing div. I want to show all the contents in the table, so the table has to go over 100% width to do so. The problem is the containing div does not reflect the size of its child. I have an example here, it's a responsive page, but the problem only happens at low widths - at high widths it is fine.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">

body, table, td {
    color      : #1D1F22;
}


#content {
    padding: 10px;
    /*overflow: hidden; */
    background-color:red;
    }

.border {
    background-color: #4385DB;
    color           : #4385DB;
}

table
{
    word-break: break-all
}

@media(min-width: 800px) {
    #content {
        width        : 98%;
    }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <table cellpadding="7" cellspacing="1" class="border">
        <tr>
            <td>VeryLongBitOfTextVeryLongBitOfText</td>
            <td>VeryLongBitOfTextVeryLongBitOfText</td>
            <td><img src="dogs.jpg" width="400" height="100" alt="trev"></td>
            <td>VeryLongBitOfTextVeryLongBitOfText</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GrimRob/qg75arbs/

Comment: why dont you consider to use scroll in the content `overflow: scroll;` ??

Comment: Why don't you try to set the image with a width in % and height auto with a min-width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your #content css if you want the table to push out the containing div.

```
display: table-cell;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using `table-layout: fixed` and some width on the table or cells.

Relevant CSS:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

`table-layout: fixed` is the *other* table layout algorithm where browser stick to what the author (you) want and don't try anymore to adapt dimensions to the content. That works if you've some indication of width wanted, like a `min-width`: http://jsfiddle.net/qg75arbs/1/

A simple min-width on table without `table-layout: fixed` also works, depends on your requirement.

Removing `table { word-break: break-all; }` also works, seems strange to allow this while trying to have large cells.

Comment: Yeah. Beat me to it. Also a really critical property when you have very large tables. It stops all the cells from comparing each other's widths across entire columns to determine an ideal cell width strategy for each col.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">

body, table, td {
    color      : #1D1F22;
}


#content {
    padding: 10px;
    /*overflow: hidden; */
    background-color:red;
    }

.border {
    background-color: #4385DB;
    color           : #4385DB;
}

table
{
    word-break: break-all;
    width:100%;
}

.img1 {
    min-width:200px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

@media(min-width: 800px) {
    #content {
        width        : 98%;
    }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <table cellpadding="7" cellspacing="1" class="border">
        <tr>
            <td>VeryLongBitOfTextVeryLongBitOfText</td>
            <td>VeryLongBitOfTextVeryLongBitOfText</td>
            <td><img src="dogs.jpg" class="img1" alt="trev"></td>
            <td>VeryLongBitOfTextVeryLongBitOfText</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the table will only shrink down to as small as the content (most of the time) and in this case you will note that each column has got to it's smallest size (1 character width), with a static width image.

In essence, the table element is not really responsive as much as you want and becomes static at a smaller size. You can scale the image or hide columns below a certain width but if you do use a table element it will always only shrink down to a certain size.